# Google Linechart - No Pointsize, Tooltips?

Tags: tooltip, visualization, linechart, google-visualization

I'm using a Linechart from Google, in which I have drawn a graph from JSON data. There are two problems I'm running into I can't seem to fix.

- Even though I have 'pointSize: 6' in my options, I still can't seem to draw any kind of point, anywhere on the graph. They just don't get visible.
- I can't seem to edit any tooltip. I've added a new column, and neither "dataTable.setValue(i, 2, 'test')" nor manually adding a new entry in the JSON file with "Tooltip":"Test" seems to work.

Anyone who knows what I'm doing wrong, or who has a better suggestion for perhaps a framework/api to use? I'm trying to visualise a datastory with simple code.

```js
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  body{
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
  }
    #linechart{
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-left: 30px}
  </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.1.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src='js/dimple.v2.1.2.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['line']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

     $(function() {
        $.getJSON('data/priceData.json', function(data) {

      var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      dataTable.addRows(1800);
      dataTable.addColumn('string', 'Date');
      dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Value');
      //dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', 'p': { 'html': true} });

      $.each(data, function(i, object){
        dataTable.setValue(i, 0, object.DateY);
        dataTable.setValue(i, 1, object.ClosePrice);
        dataTable.setValue(i, 2, object.Tooltip);
        //dataTable.setValue(i, 2, 'yo');
      });

      var options = {   
      colors: ['orange'],   
      tooltip: {isHtml: true},
        chart: {
          title: 'The Value of the Bitcoin',
          subtitle: 'in dollars (USD)'
        },

        animation: {
          duration: 1000,
          easing: 'in',
          startup: true
        },

        width: 1950,
        height: 850,
        pointSize: 6
      };

      var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart'));
      chart.draw(dataTable, options);
        });
      });
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="linechart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work using `google.visualization.LineChart` instead of `google.charts.Line`.

It gives me both points and tooltips, see here: [image]

Instead of using

```
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['line']});
```

Just try including

```
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={
        'modules':[{
          'name':'visualization',
          'version':'1',
          'packages':['corechart']
        }]
}"></script>
```

Then instead of:

```
  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart'));
```

Just try using:

```
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart'));
```

That ought to do it. Let me know if you have other problems.

Comment: This solved it for me. I guess 'Line' is a simplified version of LineChart that doesn't allow the same kind of customization. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! If you could accept the answer that would be greatly appreciated.